# Capturing actual on behalf of email id from outlook mail instead of the sender id

Tags: vba, outlook

On a daily basis, i receive hundreds of emails in outlook with no reply email id on behalf of some person for which i would like to create a database in excel using macro.

I have successfully created my database however the only challenge is fecthcing the actual email id.

**Email comes from "noreply@xxx.com; on behalf of; Ayush Varshney 
 "< varshneyayush@gmail.com >"**

weherien using OutlookMail.SenderName, i gets details as noreply@xxx.com instead of varshneyayush@gmail.com.

Is there any way i can capture on behalf email id which is varshneyayush@gmail.com in this case.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Net Sales Report").Folders("Sales")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to get the Email of the Sender:

- `OutlookMail.Sender.Address` - Will give the **OnBehalfOf** Email ID
- `OutlookMail.SenderEmailAddress` - Will Give you the **Sender** Email Id

---

```
 OutlookMail.SentOnBehalfOfName
```

I think you are looking for. This will give you the required Name.

Comment: I think, `OutlookMail.SenderEmailAddress` should give the Email ID. What is it returning ?

Comment: Nope, its giving me noreply@xxx.com instead of varshneyayush@gmail.com

Comment: @ayushvarshney Try `.Sender.Address`